Blazor component not rendering when using method to change parameters
I have a .NET 8 blazor application with a render mode of InteractiveServer.
In the app there is a component with an IsShown parameter which is used by an if statement to render the content. If I update the parameter from the host page everything works as expected. Updating the property directly using a reference to the component has no effect. Adding StateHasChanged() has no effect.
Here is the host page. The first button works. The second and third do not.
<p><button @onclick="ShowUsingParameter">Show using parameter</button></p>
<p><button @onclick="ShowUsingProperty">Show using property</button></p>
<p><button @onclick="ShowUsingMethod">Show using method</button></p>

<ExampleComponent IsShown="isComponentShown" @ref="exampleComponent"></ExampleComponent>

@code {
    private bool isComponentShown;
    private ExampleComponent exampleComponent;

    void ShowUsingParameter()
    {
        isComponentShown = true;
    }

    void ShowUsingProperty()
    {
        exampleComponent.IsShown = true;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    void ShowUsingMethod()
    {
        exampleComponent.Show();
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

And here is the component:
@if (IsShown)
{
    <h3>ExampleComponent</h3>
    
    <button @onclick="() => IsShown = false">Hide</button>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool IsShown { get; set; }

    public void Show()
    {
        IsShown = true;
    }
}


You have to call StateHasChanged inside the component:
public void Show()
{
    IsShown = true;
    StateHasChanged();
}

But do note that assigning to a parameter is disadvised. When you use this it is best to remove [Parameter] before IsShown.
